# Postgresql recordset output display in Ruby cucumber

Tags: html, sql, ruby, postgresql, cucumber

I am facing difficulty in displaying postgresql output in ruby and also if there is any way to print the same output in html.

Given below is the code and Error:

```
 Then(/^selecting source table$/) do
  require 'pg'
  conn = PGconn.connect("localhost",5433,'','', "db", "postgres", "pass")
  result = conn.exec('select EMP_ID,DEPT_ID,DEPT_NAME,EMP_NAME from EMP_TABLE')
  result.each do |row|
    puts row['EMP_ID'] + ' | ' + row['DEPT_ID'] + ' | ' + row['DEPT_NAME'] + ' | ' + row['EMP_NAME']
  end
end
```

**ERROR:**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method +' for nil:NilClass
  ./features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:45:inblock (2 levels) in ' ./features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:44:in each'
  ./features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:44:in/^selecting source table$/' ./features/PG.feature:12:in `Then selecting source table' 1 scenario (1 failed) 1 step (1 failed) 0m0.072s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your `row[whatever]` values is nil.  If you cast everything to a string it should work.

```
result.each do |row|
  puts row['EMP_ID'].to_s + ' | ' + row['DEPT_ID'].to_s + ' | ' + row['DEPT_NAME'].to_s + ' | ' + row['EMP_NAME'].to_s
end
```

Even better, you can use the `.join()` method to do that and clean up your logic at the same time.

```
result.each do |row|
  puts row.join(' | ')
end
```

**EDIT!**

My bad, that's a hash, not an array.  Give me 10 minutes and I'll give you the correct answer...

**EDIT 2**

Since it's a hash, you need to add the `.values` method in there.

```
result.each do |row|
  puts row.values.join(' | ')
end
```